# Full-bleed background videos?

Tags: video, coding-style, background

I'm wondering if anyone has thought about or come across any realistic methods for providing a full bleed background VIDEO to a site, without resulting in the site being dead slow.

Ideally I don't want to have to use Flash. And By full bleed I mean from edge to edge of the screen, like a desktop wallpaper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait for HTML 5?

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want flash then [try using silverlight](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/17/tip-trick-supporting-full-screen-mode-with-silverlight.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Since the rendering of the video (in whatever way it would work) is always done on the client, the statement "without resulting in the site being dead slow" is not really useful.

Could my current T60 Thinkpad (dualcore) render the video? I'd say yes. Could my girlfriend's Atom-based netbook do the same? I don't think so.

You've got to consider your minimum requirements for the client.

Comment: I disagree that it's not really useful. 

Surely some methods of delivering video are more intensive than others? (e.g. Flash vs JS vs Silverlight)

Comment: It usually depends on the codec used. But you're not listening to my argument. Say Silverlight is the fastest of the three methods you mention - if it still doesn't work on the Atom-based netbook I mentioned, it doesn't meet your requirement of "without the site being dead slow".

You have to set a minimum requirement for your clients and work from there.

Comment: Nono, I do see what you mean. I agree it a fairly vague way of saying it and maybe instead of saying "Without being slow", I should have said "With the best possible performance"...but you surely still understood what I meant?

Comment: I hear and I understand what you mean. I hope you find an acceptable answer, although I would not go for animated gifs ;^)

Answer (score 1):

Animated GIFs did the job since the '90s. It's a bit blocky, but if it's blurred enough no one will notice :)

Comment: I can't believe this got accepted as a correct answer. You cannot do full screen VIDEO with animated gifs. Did someone not get the joke?

Comment: http://aislian.org/tile.html is an example of this.

Well, I've seen it actually done in a few places - mostly resembling MySpace pages, probably. You can do full screen, but it will have to be quite low resolution. This is what animation was like before Flash and H.264 :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my jquery videoBG plugin

http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/

Let me know if you need any help

:)