# full page-browser html5 video without jquery

Tags: video

Trying to create a full browser html5 video effect, identical to this
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

but with video
I read this thread
[Full-bleed background videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227088/full-bleed-background-videos)
and this
[Html5 Full screen video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039909/html5-full-screen-video)

and this seems to be the best solution but uses jquery
http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/
But is there a fool proof method without jquery?

Answer (score 2):

I know this an old question but the answer is quite simple.

Just use this html5 video code, or something along these lines:

```
<video id="videobackground" preload autoplay muted>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Then apply this css:

```
#video_background { 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px; 
  right: 0px; 
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
  width: auto; 
  height: auto; 
  z-index: -1000; 
  overflow: hidden
}
```

The min-height and min-width will allow the video to maintain the aspect ratio of the video, which is usually the aspect ratio of any normal browser at a normal resolution. Any excess video bleeds off the side of the page.

Read more from my website: HTML Video Background Tutorial - HTML5 and CSS only! http://kesilconsulting.com/web-designer-magazine/html-video-background-tutorial/#ixzz2O3BPNZE6

Comment: Tested and approved.  This is a great solution.